# How structure pointer and arrow operator works?

Tags: c, structure

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

str1 
{ 
     int k; 
     struct str1 * ptr1; 
}; 

int main(void) 
{ 
         int * p1, * p2; 
         struct str1 * ptr2; 

         ptr2 = (struct str1 *) malloc(sizeof(struct str1)); 
         ptr2 -> ptr1 = (struct str1 *) malloc(sizeof(struct str1)); 
         ptr2 -> ptr1 -> ptr1 = ptr2; 
         ptr2 -> k = 7; 
         ptr2 -> ptr1 -> k = 25; 
         p1 = (int *) ptr2 -> ptr1; 
         p2 = (int *) ptr2 -> ptr1 -> ptr1;  
         printf("%d  %d\n", * p1, * p2); 

         ptr2 -> ptr1 -> ptr1 -> k ++; 
         printf("%d  %d\n", * p1, * p2); 

         ptr2 -> ptr1 -> ptr1 = ptr2 -> ptr1; 
         ptr2 -> ptr1 -> ptr1 -> k = 44; 
         printf("%d  %d\n", * p1, * p2); 

         * p1 = * p2 = 65; 
         if( ptr2 = = ptr2 -> ptr1 )  printf("Equal\n"); 
         else  printf("Not equal\n"); 
         return 0;  
}
```

In this code, I did not understand what this `ptr2 -> ptr1 -> ptr1 = ptr2;` code works. Is it attaching a structure another structure and `ptr2 -> ptr1 -> ptr1 = ptr2;` What ths code pointing at. Sorry for my bad english. Thank you for your answers.

Comment: If you look at the structure definition, and then read each line of code from the top down, you can trace through what it's pointing to pretty easily.

Answer (score 0):

The `str1` `struct` contains a pointer to another structure of type `str1`. So it is a recursive function, and you can dereference infinitely (or until you reach a `str1` `struct` that has its pointer equal to NULL. 
So `ptr2 -> ptr1 -> ptr1 = ptr2;` is assigning the current structure of `ptr2` to (recursively going up to the last) the last structure. At that point that structure's own pointer is NULL, so you cannot dereference further.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the the structure `str1` declaration is invalid as it misses the keyword `struct` which introduces a structure declaration. I am assuming it's a typo. The other typo is in *equal to* operator in this statement

```
if( ptr2 = = ptr2 -> ptr1 )  printf("Equal\n"); 
         ^^^
```

it should be `==`.

The structure `str1` is a self-referential<sup>1)</sup> structure as the `ptr1` member is pointer to itself i.e. `struct str1`.

This statement

```
         ptr2 = (struct str1 *) malloc(sizeof(struct str1));
```

allocates memory for `struct str1` type  (assuming `malloc` is success) and the pointer returned will be assigned to `ptr2`.

The in-memory view would be something like this:

```
ptr2---+
       |
       +-------+
       |   |   | 
       +-------+
         k  ptr1
```

The next statement

```
         ptr2 -> ptr1 = (struct str1 *) malloc(sizeof(struct str1));
```

does same as what its previous statement does i.e. allocates memory for `struct str1` type. The allocated memory reference will be assigned to pointer `ptr2 -> ptr1`.

The in-memory view would be something like this:

```
ptr2---+
       |
       +-------+          +-------+
       |   |   |--------->|   |   |
       +-------+          +-------+
         k  ptr1            k  ptr1
```

The next statement

```
ptr2 -> ptr1 -> ptr1 = ptr2;
```

will assign the pointer `ptr2` to `ptr2 -> ptr1 -> ptr1`. That means, after execution of this statement, both pointers `ptr2` and `ptr2 -> ptr1 -> ptr1` will point to same memory address and a loop will be created.

The in-memory view would be:

```
ptr2---+ +-----------------------------+
       | |                             |
       +-------+          +-------+    |
       |   |   |--------->|   |   |----+
       +-------+          +-------+
         k  ptr1            k  ptr1
```

Note that this statement

```
         ptr2 -> ptr1 -> ptr1 = ptr2 -> ptr1;
```

will make pointer `ptr2 -> ptr1 -> ptr1` point to structure which it is member of. The in-memory view would be:

```
ptr2---+                   +-----------+
       |                   |           |
       +-------+          +-------+    |
       |   |   |--------->|   |   |----+
       +-------+          +-------+
         k  ptr1            k  ptr1
```

Hope this clarifies your doubt. Let me know if you have any further question or confusion.

---

1). A self-referential structure is a structure in which one of its members is a pointer to the structure itself. It's commonly used in data structures like Linked List, Tree etc. implementation.